# Configuring Lambda as Target Type for ALB using Ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, ansible-2.x, aws-elb

AWS ALB has three target types - Instance, IP and Lambda.

If I want create Target group using Ansible playbook, there are only two options you can use - Instance and IP. [Link Here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/elb_target_group_module.html)

So, how to create target group for Lambda using Ansible ?

Comment: I know CloudFormation doesn't yet support this.  Could it be that Ansible ALSO doesn't yet support this?  The feature just released at the end of November.

Comment: @nicholas.hauschild - Thanks !!! Any pointer or links - How to do it using AWS CLI ?

Comment: To build out the whole ALB would require a couple CLI calls, but this is the page that would be for creating a target group (via elbv2 create-target-group).  Remember that you will need to register the target group with the load balancer once you have created it. 
 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elbv2/create-target-group.html